# AutoIt Searching values to get class variable

Tags: autoit, ini

I have a problem with searching and displaying only the values that I need. So basically I need to get a class name stored in a variable which depends on the selected item.

Every [section] of items has key 1 ( item name ), 78 ( race ), 80 ( class ).

```
78=1 ; human - race
80=1 ; knight - class
80=2 ; archer - class
80=8 ; mage - class

78=2 ; orc - race
80=1 ; berskerer - class
80=2 ; hunter - class
80=8 ; sorc - class

78=4 ; elf - race
80=1 ; swashbuckler - class
80=2 ; ranger - class
80=8 ; elementalist - class

78=8 ; dragonscion - race
80=15 ; scion - class
```

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/DUwhVAxY

Here is zip file with 2 images and .ini file http://uploaded.net/file/eleih11o.

In the 1st image is my code that works, and in the 2nd image is an example of what I need; just a variable with class name.

Here is one more image with all the stuff:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to download your files. Do you need help to find a way to get the values from the correct section via Regex pattern?

Comment: What does your _FileOpen() function do? I am not understanding what you are trying to do...

Comment: _FileOpen() opens .ini file, Im trying to get class name of a item from that file like i posted above. (?s) according to regex101 means: s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
The \[(\d+)\] catches numbers which look like this [12345] [2132123] [12]
and the .*? means that it matches anything between the number and the \v.
The \v stands for a vertical tab sign and finally the (\V+) matches all the vertical tabs after the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get but still it will fail since you have no standard seperators and/or items.

```
Case $hFinddAllButton
            GUICtrlSetData($hList, '')
            Redim $afound[0][3]
            Local $sCout = 0
            Local $sCounterText[0]
            Local $sCounterNum[0]
            For $i = 0 To UBound($matches)-1
                 If StringInStr($matches[$i][2], GUICtrlRead($hSearchInput)) Then
                     _ArrayAdd($afound, $matches[$i][0] &'|'& $matches[$i][1] &'|'& $matches[$i][2])
                     ReDim $sCounterText[UBound($sCounterText) +1]
                     ReDim $sCounterNum[UBound($sCounterNum) +1]
                     $sCounterText[$sCout] = $matches[$i][2]
                     $sCounterNum[$sCout] = $matches[$i][0]
                     $sCout += 1
                 EndIf
            Next
            For $s = 0 To UBound($sCounterText) -1
;~              ConsoleWrite($sCounterText[$s] & @LF)
;~              _ArrayAdd($afound, $matches[$i][0] &'|'& $matches[$i][1] &'|'& $matches[$i][2])
                Local $sSplit = StringSplit($sCounterText[0], " ", 2)
                Local $sSplit2 = StringSplit($sCounterText[$s], " ", 2)
                GUICtrlSetData($hList, '[' & $sCounterNum[$s] &'] ' & $sSplit[0] & " Biltz (" & GUICtrlRead($hSearchInput) & ") - " & $sCounterText[$s])
            Next
```